# Post Modified date in a formated way in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime

Getting the post_modified date is: `2013-07-11 01:45:40`.

I DON'T NEED the time (01:45:40) here.

I need the date portion to be displayed as: **July 11, 2013**.

I'm aware about PHP Date & Time function, and also aware about [WordPress date and time functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time).

But I'm afraid I can't understand how to get it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP's [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) along with [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). It converts the given date into a timestamp and then back.

**Code:**

```
<?php

$date = "2013-07-11 01:45:40";
$timestamp = strtotime($date);

echo date('F d, Y', $timestamp); //output: July 11, 2013

?>
```